# Entity framework 4 code first, use the same model to multiple tables?

Tags: entity-framework-4

Im using Entity Framework 4 with code first. I have a model and i want to be able to map this model to a different table in the database based on a configuration file.

Example model:

```
 public class Statistic
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string jobName { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public int pages { get; set; }
}
```

Each customer has a configuration file where the table name that should be used is specified. So each customer should then have its own table (in the same database) with the model above.

How can i do this with Entity Framework 4?

I tried this in my DbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Statistic>().ToTable(tabelName);
```

But what EF does when i use this is to change the existing table name to the new tableName, not creating and using a new one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. Each class can be mapped only once per mapping set (per context in common cases). Why? Because the access point to database is a DbSet (or ObjectSet in ObjectContext API) and it is simply created this way:

```
var set = dbContext.Set<Statistics>();
```

How should EF know which mapping of `Statistics` class should be used? It must know which mapping to use to query correct table and to save changes to correct table. You can probably argue that it could be defined as parameter but that would expose mapping details outside to upper layer - that is undesirable.

Edit:

If your application logic never needs access to more than one customer's statistics you can create mapping per customer dynamically. You need:

- Create instance of `DbModelBuilder` and define mapping (or fill `Configurations`) - in this step you will provide the name of the table for current customer
- Call `Build` method to get `DbModel` instance
- Call `Compile` on `DbModel` instance to get DbCompiledModel instance
- **Cache compiled model somewhere**. Model compilation is expensive operation and you need to do it only once per each customer (and per each application restart).
- Pass compiled model to `DbContext` constructor and use that context instance to access data only for that customer

If you need to simultaneously access data for multiple customers you must do it through SQL.

Comment: Thank you, i suspected that this was the case :)